# How to create an android Bottom sheet that fits the size of the sheet with view always aligned to bottom?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, bottom-sheet

I had a bit of trouble figuring out how to word this one when researching so I've made a quick mockup of what I'm trying to achieve below.
my app has a persistent bottom sheet and I would like the contents of the sheet to be resized based on whether the sheet is expanded or half expanded.

My sheet consists of a recycler view and a view at the bottom with some buttons. Currently, the contents of the sheet are always sized as though the sheet is full expanded. This means that the buttons are not displayed unless the sheet is fully expanded and much of the recycler view is also hidden behind the cropped-off sheet. What I want to happen is for the buttons to always be displayed at the bottom of the sheet, even when said sheet is half expanded, and for the recyclerview to fill whatever space is left. Is this possible in a persistent bottom sheet and if now, what means should I use to achieve this? And help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Mockup]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the buttons layout to always be displayed at the bottom of the sheet by setting its `y` coordinate by tracking the bottom sheet sliding using `addBottomSheetCallback` callbacks:

```
val bottomSheet = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.bottom_sheet)
val bottomLayout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.button_layout)

// initial setting the y coordinates of the bottom layout
bottomSheet.post {
    val bottomSheetVisibleHeight = bottomSheet.height - bottomSheet.top
    bottomLayout.y =
        (bottomSheetVisibleHeight - bottomLayout.height).toFloat()
}

BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).apply {

    addBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
        
            // set the y coordinates of the bottom layout on bottom sheet slide
            val bottomSheetVisibleHeight = bottomSheet.height - bottomSheet.top
            bottomLayout.y =
                (bottomSheetVisibleHeight - bottomLayout.height).toFloat()
        }

        override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
        }
    })
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--    Main Layout -->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:behavior_hideable="false"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="#CFE2F3"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_layout"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/button_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="#FF03DAC5"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="cancel" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="ok" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! For some reason this didn't exactly work for me. That could be due to how my complex layout within the bottom sheet, but it definitely showed me what I needed! My solution turned out to be setting bottomlayout.y to the negative value of BottomSheet.top

Comment: @BooleanCheese could you please post your solution. I am trying to achieve something opposite. I have two bottom sheets layered on top of one another one, the one at the bottom nests a recyclerview like what you have and the other one has an edit text layout with a button. When the edit text is focused, the lower bottom sheet should remain at the bottom and be covered by the soft keyboard, while the top bottom sheet moves with the soft keyboard. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @VictorOkech I can attempt to post my solution in a bit but I'm not quite sure it's applicable to your issue. Two bottom sheets layered on top of each other? Is there a reason you need to bottom sheets? Can you expand them separately of each other? I think the behavior you're looking for is probably better achieved by playing around with android:windowSoftInputMode in your activity in the manifest. try android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan". Maybe even "adjustNothing"

Comment: @BooleanCheese the two bottom sheets are related. The first bottom sheet has a recyclerview that displays a list of text and the second one is an edittext with a button to post new text to this list. When the first bottom sheet is expanded the second one should still be collapsed and once the edittext on the second one gets focus the soft keyboard should push it up over the first bottom sheet.

Comment: @VictorOkech I don't believe this solution would work for you. This is about resizing the view within the sheet, it doesn't effect the sheet itself. That being said, if you save a reference to BottomSheetBehavior.from(YOUR_SHEET) you should be able to programmatically set it to BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED or BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN when you want.

Comment: can someone help me implement the same in a jetpack compose ModalBottomSheeLayout.